# Finding validator address of a block

Tags: etherscan, validators, beacon

How to reliably find the validator address of a block?
Relay API has gaps wherein some blocks are missing.

Is there any other reliable way to get the validator address?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the address to which the rewards for the offered block have been sent

```
const { Web3 } = require('web3').   // "web3": "^4.2.1"
const { isAddress } = require('web3-validator')
const web3 = new Web3("https://virginia.rpc.blxrbdn.com")

async function GetLastNBlocks(n) {
    latestBlock = await web3.eth.getBlockNumber() - BigInt(1)
    web3.eth.getBlock(latestBlock).then((data, err) => {
        // console.log(latestBlock, "data:", data)
        console.log(data.miner, isAddress(data.miner)) // data.miner
    })
}
GetLastBlocks()
```

You can see the block validator in the browser https://beaconcha.in/block/18475010 -> Proposer